# How to Unstage and Discard in a single command in git

Tags: git

In git,
to unstage a file `git reset HEAD <filename>`  is used
to discard changes  `git checkout  <filename>` is used

Is there a way to combine these two commands in one?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try

```
git checkout HEAD <filename>
```