# Unstage all files and abandon merge

Tags: git

I was running a simple merge and expecting no conflicts, and I ran `git merge my_dev_branch`

However I got a merge conflict which looked messy to resolve, and made me think that I wasn't clear on my branch history.  Rather than resolve the conflict I would like to abandon the merge and go back to where I was before.

Two questions:

1. Am I right in thinking that I could clean out my staging area by running `git checkout HEAD <filename>` on each file per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225363/how-to-unstage-and-discard-in-a-single-command-in-git) and that this would amount to abandoning the merge?
2. Is there a way I can do this in one command?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try `git merge --abort`. Handy, eh?

Comment: ;-) perfect.  Much appreciated.